# how to repeat exception handling on python

Tags: python, pandas, exception

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas, xlrd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import csv

end = datetime.now() # 마지막 날을 오늘로 설정
start = end - timedelta(days=250) # 시작 날을 오늘로 부터 250일 전으로 설정

stock_code = pandas.read_excel('/home/ubuntu/trading/Book1.xlsx', dtype=str, encoding="CP949").as_matrix()

#250일 모멘텀 계산
for st in stock_code:
    eventcode = st[0]
    try:
        df = web.DataReader("krx:%s" % eventcode, "google", start, end) #코스피이면 구글에서 데이터 받음
    except:
        df = web.DataReader("%s.KQ" % eventcode, "yahoo", start, end) #코스닥이면 야후에서 데이터 받음
        try:
            df=web.DataReader("%s.KQ" % eventcode, "yahoo", start, end) #코스닥이면 야후에서 데이터 받음
        except:
            df = web.DataReader("%s.KQ" % eventcode, "yahoo", start, end)  # 코스닥이면 야후에서 데이터 받음
    close = df['Close']
    num = len(close)

    sum = 0
    for x in range(0, num - 1):
        if close[x + 1] / close[x] == 1: #당일 종가가 전날 종가와 같으면 0 추가
            sum = sum + 0
        elif close[x + 1] / close[x] > 1: #당일 종가가 전날 종가 보다 높으면 1 추가
            sum = sum + 1
        else: #당일 종가가 전날 종가가 낮으면 -1.
            sum = sum - 1
    print(sum) #최종값
```

Dear all.
I want to get the stock data from google and yahoo.
sometimes it can't get the data from yahoo. but after few second try it again, i can get data.

so I use try and except.
if i can't get data from yahoo. i want to try again 3 times.
so i put the try and except in except.
but it doesn't work.

how to i fix it?

this is errors

```
pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/003100.KQ?period1=1483019682&period2=1504655999&crumb=Vxp9S4A%5Cu002FjwQ&interval=1d&events=history
```

Comment: Try to introduce a delay between retries  using  `time.sleep()`

Answer (score 0):

You can go with sleep logic and you can limit the number of retry as well,

df = None

while df is None:

```
try:

    df = web.DataReader("krx:%s" % eventcode, "google", start, end) 

except:

sleep(1000)
df = None
```